# LibVLCSharp : 'Failed to load required native libraries.'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, libvlc

which exactly native librairies for a WPF Platform do I need from NuGet?
For the moment I installed those (see picture please) but It seems that I miss another one. Have someone an idea?
[image: Failed to load required native libraries]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to also install `VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows` nuget package and build the solution.

Probably you do not need LibVLCSharp.Forms.* nugets. They contain support for Xamarin.Forms.